# Blackberry asp.net Application : vertical scroll bar using overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, blackberry

I have a regualar HTML table to be displayed on blackberry application. It displays data perfectly fine with scroll bar using overflow property. But this scrollbar is not very user friendly, it bearly works. Pagination cannot work because the height of the table is specified by user and it will make the application very slow due to reloading.

Is there any other option to make scrollbar work properly. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're displaying this in the BlackBerry browser, then no, there is no way to improve its scroll bar.

Comment: what can be the alternate option .. ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have the page dedicated to the list of records rather than just a scrollable fixed-height table. Then you can scroll the page with the trackball/trackpad/finger-swipe to view the records, which is a lot simpler and more intuitive for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the answer is to make a version of the UI that works on a blackberry-sized screen. If your application is properly structured, that is pretty easy as its just another view on your data.

Comment: I still have to show eg. 1000 records in a table. And the height is restricted by user. So I will still need scrollbar.

Comment: Might just be me, but pulling 1000 records on a mobile device is a bit self defeating. How long do you want a user to wait to get the screen?